# 戦ぐ風に乗り光り輝く未来を translation

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

In a song by Monkey Majik ([Together](http://www.jpopasia.com/lyrics/8397/)) it says 戦ぐ風に乗り光り輝く未来を, and a translation I read says this means grab the bright future. But I don't see anywhere in this sentences that necessarily implies grabbing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: More context needed.  There might be something like "grab" following this line.  Even if there is no verb following, you should be able to tell that a verb is implied or omitted because of the particle を.  One could not translate a sentence-like phrase into Emglish without using a verb when an direct object (未来 in this case) clearly exists.  Even if there is no verb in the original, one needs to create one for the transation's sake.

Comment: From my link :
もうしこの背中に翼があったら
今すぐ君に届けたい
溢れ出す幸せを

*もうしこの背中に翼があったら
今すぐ君に届けたい
溢れ出す幸せを
戦ぐ風にのり光輝く未来を　together
いつまでも

Comment: In the line before, 溢れ出せ幸せを　means 幸せを溢れ出す, right? Is this different? Is this an implied adjective?

Comment: OK, I've read the whole thing now. The verb is 届けたい, so using "to grab" rather than "to deliver" is only free translation.  I do not want to comment on the quality of the TL; I will leave it to you.  Personally, I feel "grab" was a poor word choice because one grabs something oneself while one "delivers" something to SOMEONE ELSE.  In the second stanza, there are two things that the speaker wants to deliver to "you" ---  溢れ出す幸せ and 光輝く未来.  There are a number of mistakes in the Japanese lyrics on the page you linked to --- starting even from the first word もうし (it is もし).  DO NOT trust it.

Comment: あふれ出す is an intransitive verb so one cannot say 幸せを溢れ出す.  One must say 幸せが溢れ出す.

幸せが溢れ出す is a sentence but 溢れ出す幸せ is only a noun phrase.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with the lyrics on the site you linked. The relevant portion of the lyrics shown on Uta-Net's lyrics page for [Together by MONKEY MAJIK](http://www.uta-net.com/song/64937/) read as follows:

> もしこの背中に翼があったら
>   いますぐキミに届けたい
>   あふれだす幸せを
>
> そよぐ風に乗り
>   ひかり輝く未来を
>   Together いつまでも

The phrases 「あふれだす幸せ」 and 「そよぐ風に乗りひかり輝く未来」 are both intended to be the objects of the verb 届ける. If we were to rearrange the lyrics into a complete sentence, it would probably look something like the following:

> もしこの背中に翼があったら、いますぐキミにあふれだす幸せとそよぐ風に乗ってひかり輝く未来を届けたい。

The translation is just a bad one. That's all there is to it.